# MYSQL: Parallel execution of multiple statements within a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a procedure (`procedureA`) that loops through a table and calls another procedure (`procedureB`) with variables derived from that table.

Each call to `procedureB` is independent of the last call.

When I run `procedureA` my system resources show a maximum CPU use of `50%` (I assume that is 1 out of my 2 CPU cores).

However, if I open two instances of the `mysql` terminal and execute a query in both terminals, both CPU cores are used (CPU usage can reach close to 100%).

How can I achieve the same effect inside a stored procedure?

I want to do something like this:

```
BEGIN
    CALL procedureB(var1); -> CPU CORE #1
    SET var1 = var1+1;
    CALL procedureB(var1); -> CPU CORE #2
END
```

I know its not going to be that easy... 
Any tips?

Comment: If they're really independent, why call them sequentially instead of as separate independent processes?

Comment: @Denis Yeah, thats what I'm saying... my question is 'how?'

Comment: @Denis I want to avoid calling them from an external program because that will create lag in its own right.

Comment: Possibly, but isn't that your best chance of doing so easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within MySQL, to get something done asynchronously you'd have to use an `CREATE EVENT`, but I'm not sure whether creating one is allowed within a stored procedure. (On a side note: async. inserts can of course be done with `INSERT DELAYED`, but that's 1 thread, period).

Normally, you are much better of having a couple of processes/workers/deamons which can be accessed asynchronously by you program and have their own database connection, but that of course won't be in the same procedure.

Comment: I looked up events, but it seems like they are used for scheduled actions; I need mine to execute immediately.  If the events are prebuilt how would how would I go about executing them in parallel from a stored procedure?

Comment: Also it may be relevant that my entire database is in-memory only. I do not use `MYISAM` or `InnoDB`

Comment: You can't in native MySQL: the best you can do asynchronously is to let things start a tiny bit in the future. And you can't prebuild events, only schedule them on creation. Really, go for an option in your actual program/script/whatever you use that leverages multiple connections. You can have a simple ever-running daemon ready to go with little overhead. There is no multi-threading or asynchronous call you can make in MySQL itself. SQL isn't built for actual programming of this kind.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own daemon as a stored procedure, and schedule multiple copies of it to run  at regular intervals, say every 5 minutes, 1 minute, 1 second, etc.

use get_lock() with N well defined lock names to abort the event execution if another copy of the event is still running, if you only want up to N parallel copies running at a time.

Use a "job table" to list the jobs to execute, with an ID column to identify the execution order.  Be sure to use good transaction and lock practices of course - this is re-entrant programming, after all.

Each row can define a stored procedure to execute and possibly the parameters.  You can even have multiple types of jobs, job tables, and worker events for different tasks.

Use PREPARE and EXECUTE with the CALL statement to dynamically call stored procedures whose names are stored in strings.

Then just add rows as needed to the job table, even inserting in big batches, and let your worker events process them as fast as they can.

I've done this before, in both Oracle and MySQL, and it works well.  Be sure to handle errors and log them somewhere, as well as success, for that matter, for debugging and auditing, as well as performance tuning.  N=#CPUs may not be the best fit, depending on your data and the types of jobs.  I've seen N=2xCPUs work best for data-intensive tasks, where lots of parallel disk I/O is more important than computational power.