# Can MySQL parallelize UNION subqueries (or anything at all)?

Tags: mysql, parallel-processing, partitioning

I use a partitioned table with a large amount of data. According to MySQL docs, it is on the ToDo list that:

> Queries involving aggregate functions such as SUM() and COUNT() can
>   easily be parallelized.

... but, can I achieve the same functionality using UNION subqueries? Are they parallelized, or do I have to create a multithreaded client to run concurrent queries with all the possible partition keys?

---

**Edit:**

The question is not strictly about UNION or subqueries. I would like to utilize as many cores as possible for my queries. Is there any way to do this (and make sure it's done) without paralellizing my application?

Any good documentation about MySQL's current parallelizing capabilities?

Comment: do you mean `

    select a.sum, b.count
    from 
    (select sum(x) as sum from xxx) as a
    (select count(*) as count from xxx) as b
`
insted of
`
    select sum(x) as sum, count(*) as count
    from xxx
`

Comment: @Luis I'm not neccessarily talking about aggregate functions only. But if I do then something like: `SELECT AVG(number) FROM table WHERE class=1 UNION SELECT AVG(number) FROM table WHERE class=2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, currently the only way to use more than one thread/core to run queries in your application, is to use more than one connection. This of course makes it impossible to run parallel queries that are part of a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks! I only care about the speed of my SELECTs, so transactions are not really an issue.

Comment: In PHP I've been able to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.reap-async-query.php in order to run 4 queries in parallel on 4 core server.

Answer (score 1):

The different queries that are UNIONed together in one larger query aren't really subqueries, strictly speaking.

- The queries are run in order
- The data type of the columns is determined by the first query
- By default, identical rows are dropped (UNION defaults to DISTINCT)
- The result set is not finished building until all queries are run

...there is no way to parallelize the different queries, as they are all really part of the same query.

You may want to try runing the different queries in parallel from your code, and then mashing the results up together in your code once the queries all complete.

The documentation on UNIONs can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html).

Comment: Neither the fact that `DISTINCT` is the default, nor that the row types must be known before sending the result prohibit the parallel processing. From the linked document: *However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.*

Comment: ORDER BY for individual SELECTs, yes - but without the adding of parentheses, an ORDER BY at the end of that set of queries will order the whole result set.

Comment: Note that the list I gave above is not necessarily a list of reasons why some parallelization could never happen, but they are all related to how the different parts of a UNIONed query interact.

Comment: I understand that it can not occur *in all cases*. My question was whether *does it occur at all*? (And if yes, how can I ensure that it does).

Comment: *"The queries are run in order"* - are you shure about this one?

Comment: Pretty confident, yeah `SELECT 0, SYSDATE() 
UNION ALL 
SELECT SLEEP(1), SYSDATE() 
UNION ALL 
SELECT SLEEP(1), SYSDATE()`

Comment: My point is that if this behavior is not documented then it is not more than *how it is done now* and can change any time.

Answer (score 1):

I think a similar question was answered here.
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,84453,84453

(May be I should have posted this as a comment, but I honestly couldn't find a comment button anywhere around here.)

Comment: Good find.  If you're looking to solve the same issue as that guy (he didn't want to split up his queries because of high latency) you could always create a stored procedure that would run multiple queries for you and then return them all at once.

Comment: You'll get access to commenting at 50 reputation. See http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: Similar question but there was no satisfying answer. Or was the answer NO between the lines? Anywas, I certailny did my **google: mysql parallel** before posting the question.

Comment: Hi @TehShrike , Could you please point me to some example.

Answers to the SOF question in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272256/mysql-parallel-execution-of-multiple-statements-within-a-stored-procedure were suggesting that it is not easy to get parallel execution in MySQL Stored Procedures except for the possibility of using CREATE EVENT or INSERT DELAYED

Comment: @rineez Aye, I can elaborate some more.  Join the MySQL chat room, I generally hang out there http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you are out of luck.

However, MySQL 8.0 has a *small* number of other cases where the Optimizer will use multiple cores.

In general, when you need parallelism, you need parallel I/O more than multiple CPUs.  And that is rarely available.